# VBA Automatically run macro that pulls data from a website

Tags: vba, excel, api

I've written a macro that uses an API to pull data from a website to get current prices. I want this to run automatically every 10 minutes say to get a rough idea of live prices.

I have tried to do this by using the following:

```
Sub Test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "MyMacro"
End Sub
```

However it doesn't seem to be working... I'm new to getting subs to run automatically so am probably overlooking something.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What you have posted should automatically run `MyMacro` 10 minutes after `Test` is run.  What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to be working"?  Does it give an error message?  (If so, what is the error?)  Does it not run `MyMacro` at all?  (If so, is it because you closed Excel completely during the 10 minute interval?)  Does `MyMacro` not do what you think it should do?  (If so, post the code for `MyMacro`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be happening is that you are scheduling the macro to run one time only. You need to set it up so that it reschedules itself after the first time:

```
Sub Schedule()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "MyMacro"
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
    Schedule ' (Reschedule at the top to run every 10 minutes)

    'Do something...

    '(Or reschedule at the bottom to run 10 minutes *after* the execution)
End Sub
```

Comment: This was what was happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a great idea to has Excel running constantly, unless you have a machine devoted to ONLY that.  As an alternative, you can use the Task Scheduler to open Excel and run a Macro.  In the Create Task dialog, click the Triggers tab. Then click the New button. In the New Trigger dialog, you will see an Advanced Settings section. It has a Repeat Task area. You can put a check mark in that box and choose a preset value or type your own.

[image]

See the screen shot below.